# Natural extension of basis for a field extension is a basis for tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $A$ is a $k$-algebra, and $l/k$ a finite field extension.

> Claim: if $b_1 =1 , b_2,\ldots, b_n$ is a $k$-basis for $l/k$, then $1 \otimes b_1, \ldots, 1 \otimes b_n$ is a free $A$-basis for $A \otimes_k l$.

It is clear that these are a generating set with coefficients in $A$, but why are they $A$-independent?

Comment: You can take a basis $A= \sum_j k a_j$ then the $a_j \otimes_k b_m$ are a $k$-basis of $A\otimes_k L$ and $\sum_{j,m} c_{j,m} \ a_j \otimes_k b_m = 0$ means all the $c_{j,m}=0$. Thus from a non-trivial $A$-linear relation you get a bunch of $k$-linear relations on the $a \otimes_k b_m$, one of them is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I was just being dumb, thanks reuns. Here is the solution for closure.

Take a basis $A = \sum_j ka_j$ (not necessarily finite). Then the $a_j \otimes_k b_m$ are a $k$-basis for the tensor product. Assume we have
$$
   0 = \sum_{i} a_i' (1 \otimes b_i)  
$$
for arbitrary $a_i' \in A$. Then
$$
0 = \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} (a_j \otimes b_i)
$$ 
with only finitely many $c_{i,j} \neq 0$. Then we have all $c_{i,j} = 0$, so $a_i' = \sum_j c_{i,j} a_j = 0$ for all $i$.